# User not defined in public page with sailsjs passport

Tags: sails.js, passport-local

I've used sails-generate-auth to add an authentication to my website. The authentication is working fine: I can only access public pages if I'm not authenticated.

My index page is public, its controller's policy is set to true:

```
/config/policies.js
'*': ['passport', 'sessionAuth'],

'auth': {
   '*': ['passport']
},
'IndexController' : true
```

**Problem:** In my layout I want to display either the login button or the username:

```
/views/layout.ejs
[....]
<% if ( user != undefined ){ %>
    <li><a href="/logout"><%= user.username %> <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li> 
<% }else{ %>
    <li><a href="/login"></i>Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a></li> 
<% } %>  
[...]
```

However, I can't acces the **user** variable on these public pages, I get

```
user not defined
```

I managed to display the username (ie access the **user** variable) only on views generated in restricted controllers.

====== New little problem:

On the login page, the variable user is defined, so the if statement is true and the user.name is displayed in the layer. However the user is not logged yet, and the result is that user.name shows "undefined":

[image: screen of the problem]

I tried:

```
<% if ((typeof user) != 'undefined' && (user.name != 'undefined')){ %>
```

but "undefined" still show in the layout. With this:

```
<% if ((typeof user) != 'undefined' && (typeof (user.name) != 'undefined')){ %>
```

The statement is never true and "Login" is displayed on every pages, even after login.

Any idea how to proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the *passport policy* for the *IndexController*. You will have access to the user and will still be able to see the page without being logged.

Indeed, [the *passport policy* initialize passport and set the *user* variable in the response](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/blob/master/templates/api/policies/passport.js#L30) while [the *sessionAuth policy* is controlling if the user is authenticated](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/api/policies/session-auth-js) to allow him to access to the controller.

Comment: Thanks ! That was the solution for the initial question :)
However before marking the question solved, I have a new problem... (see the edit of the first post)

Comment: It works for me with your original code. I'm having a look, but maybe it could be another question?

Comment: I could reproduce a similar error. Are you sure that the `name` attribute exists in your `User` model? In `sails-generate-auth`, the attribute is [`user.username`](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/blob/master/templates/api/models/User.js#L6).

Comment: Ok shame on me. It was as simple as that... thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if (user)` or `if (typeof user === 'undefined')`

```
<% if (user){ %>
  <li><a href="/logout"><%= user.username %> <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li> 
<% }else{ %>
  <li><a href="/login"></i>Login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a></li> 
<% } %>
```